# Regex to get two set of string?

Tags: regex

I have a String as vsc-nigulp-25.00.00-200.tar , I have to get two set of outputs as vsc-nigulp and 25.00.00-200 from the given string. 
What Regex conditions would be giving these two set of outputs?

Comment: What language (if any) are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: The `vsc-nigulp` regex would match the first part you wish to retrieve, while the `25\.00\.00-200` regex would match the second (we need more than a single sample of your input to give a meaningful answer). Will your versionning scheme always follow the `xx.xx.xx-xxx` format?

Comment: I have to pass these values to ansible , I have tried using https://regex101.com/r/8BDmFj/1

Comment: @Aaron yes xx.xx.xx-xxx this will follow the same pattern

Comment: I don't know ansible, but check if it can use back-references / refer to capturing groups, and use the following pattern : https://regex101.com/r/8BDmFj/2

Comment: Thanks @Aaron  I am able find the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
(^[a-zA-Z-]*)(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}-\d{3})
```

- Beginning of text, any number of letters or dashes
- Followed by your pattern of numbers and dashes

See: https://regex101.com/r/0yjz0Z/1